# How to use jQuery .html() function with ul elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change address data templates (street, home number, city code etc.) when someone set in my select type field value US.
I have done something like that on div's but I had problem when this data are in ul type.

I don't have too much expirience in jQuery. **Could you tell me where I have an error, or how can I use .html function on ul elements?**

**This is HTML code (I'm using Open Power Template):**

```
<ul class="address" id="profileAddressDefault">
<li>
{u:@$form::getElement('address_city_code')}{u:$form::getElement('address_city_name')}
</li>
<li>
{u:$form::getElement('address_street')}
{u:$form::getElement('address_street_hn')}
{u:entity('nbsp')}/{u:entity('nbsp')}
{u:$form::getElement('address_street_an')}
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="address" id="profileAddressUs" style="display: none;">
<li>
{u:$form::getElement('address_city_name')}
{u:@$form::getElement('address_city_code')}
</li>
<li>
{u:$form::getElement('address_street_hn')}
{u:entity('nbsp')}/{u:entity('nbsp')}
{u:$form::getElement('address_street_an')}
{u:$form::getElement('address_street')}
</li>
</ul>
```

**This is my jQuery code:**

```
$j('#country_id').change(function() {

    if($j('#country_id').val()=='US') {
        $j('#profileAddressDefault').html($j('#profileAddressUs').html());
    } 
});
```

Comment: Check the console and see what errors you're getting.

Comment: But console show me that I don't have some library, which is not need to my method. Nothing more

Comment: Can you post the output of your console? This will help provide clarity.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://test.dev/js/lib/select2/select2_locale_en.js` but as I said, I don't use this library and before my changes system worked fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$j('#profileAddressDefault').html($j('#profileAddressUs').html());
```

Assuming $j('#profileAddressUs').html() returns an element ID:

```
.html($j('#profileAddressUs').html());
```

The code above is missing the "#" to select the inner ID.

Better way to do this:

```
$j('#country_id').change(function() {
    if($j('#country_id').val()=='US') {
        var elemID = "#" + $j('#profileAddressUs').html();
        $j('#profileAddressDefault').html(elemID);
    } 
});
```

Comment: $j('#profileAddressUs').html() returns a html code. This code should replace code in ul with #profileAddressDefault ID